# sorting numbers in a given order in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

In excel I want sort columns in a given order. For example, Given that I have a list of columns of Id and beat B, I want sort columns so that ID is in order to the given oder and corresponding value of beat matches to the sorted order of ID.

Given the following list of ID and beat

```
33345666 3

44563334 7   

39304955 0

22352564 3

76488854 4

23456784 0
```

What I want to do is sort columns of occurrence in order of ID in following order

```
44563334    
33345666    
23456784    
22352564    
39304955    
76488854
```

So that it would look like:

```
44563334 7

33345666 3

23456784 0

22352564 3

39304955 0

76488854 4
```

What is the easiest and convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if your list giving the order you want to put the items into is in sheet2 A1:A6 you could add a column with

```
=MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6,0)
```

then sort on that. Just be aware that any IDs that aren't in your list will return a #N/A error. You can get around this by wrapping it in an IFERROR function, eg

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6,0),99999)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column with the order you need and then sort basing on that column.